# TypeError: __call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'message_id' Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

HTML code

```
 <a href="{% url 'front_end:office_message' message_id=message.id %}"><img src="{{message.profile_image.url}}" alt="" /></a>
```

views.py

```
def office_message(request, message_id):
message = OfficeStaffMessage.objects.filter(id=message_id)
context = {"messages": message}
return render(request, "about-us.html", context)
```

urls.py

```
 path("messages/<int:message_id>/", office_message, name="office_message"),
```

Comment: try removing message_id= just Use message.id

Comment: didn't work. actually, the id is getting passed from the template and shows the problem in url.py